# Seeking Substantial Subcollections

Tags: code-golf, number, combinatorics

*(thanks to @JonathanFrech for the title)*

### Challenge

Write a program or function that, given a collection of positive integers \$S\$ and a positive integer \$n\$, finds as many non-overlapping subcollections \$T_1, T_2, ..., T_k\$ of \$S\$ as possible, such that the sum of every \$T_m\$ is equal to \$n\$.

#### Example

Given \$S=\lbrace1,1,2,2,3,3,3,5,6,8\rbrace\$ and \$n=6\$, you could take the following subcollections to get \$k=3\$:

- \$T_1=\lbrace1,1,2,2\rbrace\$
- \$T_2=\lbrace3,3\rbrace\$
- \$T_3=\lbrace6\rbrace\$

And the remaining elements \$\lbrace3,5,8\rbrace\$ are not used. However, there is a way to get \$k=4\$ separate subcollections:

- \$T_1=\lbrace1,2,3\rbrace\$
- \$T_2=\lbrace1,5\rbrace\$
- \$T_3=\lbrace3,3\rbrace\$
- \$T_4=\lbrace6\rbrace\$

This leaves \$\lbrace2,8\rbrace\$ unused. There is no way to do this with 5 subcollections<sup>1</sup>, so \$k=4\$ for this example.

#### Input

Input will be a collection of positive integers \$S\$, and a positive integer \$n\$. \$S\$ may be taken in any reasonable format: a comma- or newline-separated string, an actual array/list, etc. You may assume that \$S\$ is sorted (if your input format has a defined order).

#### Output

The output may be either:

1. the maximal number of subcollections \$k\$; or
2. any collection which has \$k\$ items (e.g., the list of subcollections \$T\$ itself), in any reasonable format.

Note that there is not guaranteed to be any subcollections with sum \$n\$ (i.e. some inputs will output `0`, `[]`, etc.)

#### Test cases

```
n, S -> k
1, [1] -> 1
1, [2] -> 0
2, [1] -> 0
1, [1, 1] -> 2
2, [1, 1, 1] -> 1
3, [1, 1, 2, 2] -> 2
9, [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7] -> 2
9, [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7] -> 1
8, [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6] -> 2
6, [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8] -> 4
13, [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 11, 12] -> 5
22, [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 13, 14, 14, 17, 18, 18, 21] -> 10
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest program in bytes in each language wins**. Good luck!

---

<sup>1. Mini-proof: the \$8\$ is obviously useless, but when you remove it, the total sum of \$S\$ becomes \$26\$; therefore, it can only contain up to \$4\$ non-overlapping subcollections whose sums are \$6\$.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>17 11</s>  10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 Thanks to Dennis (use count to remove the need to tie atoms together with any [quick](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Quicks))

```
Œ!ŒṖ€§Ẏċ€Ṁ
```

A dyadic link accepting a list and an integer which yields the maximal count, \$k\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWjkx7unPaoac2h5Q939R3pBrIe7mz4//9/tKGOoY4REBrrmOgYx/43AQA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWjkx7unPaoac2h5Q939R3pBrIe7mz4f3i5gz6Q@f9/dLShjkK0YWwslw6YZQRmGaGIAbEhQhjIgfGN4XygDESnJVzIGIxMwcgcl5w5RC4WAA) -- it's too slow for the larger test cases :(

#### How?

```
Œ!ŒṖ€§Ẏċ€Ṁ - Link: list L, integer I
Œ!         - all permutations
  ŒṖ€      - for €ach: all partitions (all ways to slice up each permutation)
     §     - sum each (vectorises at depth 1, so this gets the sums of the parts of
           -           each of the partitions for each permutation)
      Ẏ    - tighten  (to get a list of the sums of the parts of each possible partition)
       ċ€  - for €ach count occurrences of I
         Ṁ - maximum
```

Comment: It makes the program even slower, but `Œ!ŒṖ€§Ẏċ€Ṁ` saves a byte.

Comment: Oh, that was an oversight, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
Œ!ŒṖ€ẎŒP€Ẏ§;EɗƇẈṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWjkx7unPaoac3DXX1HJwVAGIeWW7uenH6s/eGujoc7G/7//x9tqKMAREZAFPvfGAA)

Outputs \$k\$ if there is a \$T\$, \$0\$ otherwise. Very slow.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œ€.œOQOZ
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174921/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORHTWv0jk72D/SP@v8/2lDHCAiNgdAklssEAA) NOTE: Extremely slow, so times out for most test cases beyond the size of 6..

**Explanation:**

```python
œ           # All permutations of the (implicit) input-list
 €.œ        # Take all partitions of each permutation
    O       # Sum each
     Q      # Check for each if it's equal to the (implicit) integer-input
      O     # Then sum each
       Z    # And take the maximum (implicitly flattens the list of lists)
            # (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 115 bytes

```javascript
k=>f=([i,...s])=>i?Math.max(...[i,...s].map((_,j)=>(e[j]=~~e[j]+i,_=f(s),e[j]-=i,_))):e.filter(_=>_==k).length;e=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCoJAEIbvPYXHGVqX1CJMxm7eegIREVt11VRciU6@uq1LdYiCbxn@nY9/6uyeqXyUw2R3/VUsES0NhQVBLBnnXCVIoTxfsqnit@wB@uu90HkASFmtDRBxndA8r2MrWUoFKGRrsklHRDwJXsh2EiOkFKZEDfJWdOVUBYLiZAk2ed@pvhW87UuIwEOIHWZpXE2C@C34H8EzHAzHP6bPrBc/BGc95pqWvWlxdvqt5ebw8gQ)